# Spring mvc loading JS with Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot. I have this structure for a simple test app:

[image]

What I do in my TestController is to get 2 path variables and load index.html:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/{vara}/{varb}")
    public String index(@PathVariable(value="vara") String vara, @PathVariable(value="varb") String varb) {
        return"/index.html";
    }
}
```

and the index.html is empty, clean html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
TEST
</body>
</html>
```

so typing **localhost:8080/abbas/mirza** in my browser and everything looks ok and the html page loads easily. 
I have 2 js files, **test.js** and **/js/testb.js** which both have this line of code inside.

```
var s = {};
```

Now I add this

```
<script src="/test.js"></script>
```

and everything is still ok  and I can view the test.js code, but when I add

```
<script src="/js/testb.js"></script>
```

the page throws an exception

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and when I try to open the testb.js file it shows me this

[image]

if I move testb.js into the webapp itself, it will be loaded with no problem. I'm quite newbie using the Spring mvc and still confused with all the configuration regarding routings and accessing resources.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:(link to github)** https://github.com/arashzz/test22

Comment: What are you doing? Are you trying to write html in js file and then import file within itself? Sound to edgy to me!

Comment: @arash-moeen Could you share this project on GitHub?  I don't see the problem based on the data provided...

Comment: @arseniyandru no I'm not, that's how it's been shown as the error. I only have 1 line of code in my html

Comment: @punkrocker27ka if i remove the controller routing like that it will simply work but when it gets loaded like that then it behaves like this. I'll share on GitHub and will post here

Comment: @punkrocker27ka just added the github link in the question.

Comment: I have no problem with your code it works (in eclipse). http://localhost:8080/fdsf/fdgfd this worked and returned TEST. Try re-importing it maybe.

Comment: @arseniyandru please try to open the console and see if there is an error i described or not when importing the testb.js? Because the html is rendered anyway but the js file is not loaded.

Comment: I would just recommend you to add spring-starter-thymeleaf to your dependencies and follow convention for spring-boot web apps. Store everything in main/resources/templates and main/resources/static/js . Like here https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@RequestMapping` pattern you're using is so broad that the path to your JavaScript file *testb.js* matches it and thus the index page is served in lieu of your js file causing the syntax error to occur.

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping("/{vara}/{varb}")
```

**JavaScript Path:**

```
/js/testb.js
```

This matches that pattern where `vara=js` and `varb=testb.js`

Your other JavaScript file is located at `/test.js` and thus doesn't match the pattern and is served correctly.

**Solution:**

Adjust the @RequestMapping pattern to something more narrow such as:

```
@RequestMapping("/placeholder/{vara}/{varb}")
```

Comment: I did exactly as you mentioned but still the same error message

Comment: @arash-moeen I've updated my answer.  Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: ok that solved the issue but that means the only way I can load the js file from another folder is to have the URL narrowed like that. right?

Comment: @arash-moeen Correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `<script src="js/testb.js"></script>` without `/`as index.html and js directory are in same directory level

Comment: it throws 404 error because without / it will try to access it from `http://localhost:8080/abbas/js/testb.js`